# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__'

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am trying to use the path of google appengine in my django project.

```
import google

PYTHON_LIB = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(google.__file__))
```

this leads me the following Attribute error.I have checked google directory has **init**.py file.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__'
```

Do anyone have any idea where i am missing?

Comment: Please add more information so we can understand whats going wrong

Comment: Please add your efforts in explaining the question

Comment: i am using google app engine i want to use the path of the app engine. so i have written the code PYTHON_LIB = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(google.__file__)) but it returns above error

Comment: analyze google object, i.e. `print(dir(google))`

Comment: What has led you to believe that the module has a presence on disk at all?

Comment: this is the result of print google.__path__ ['/home/ansuman/Ansuman/mauthor_new/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google', '/home/ansuman/Ansuman/mauthor_new
/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google', '/etc/google_appengine/google', '/etc/google_appengine/google', '/etc/googl
e_appengine/google', '/etc/google_appengine/google', '/etc/google_appengine/google', '/etc/google_appengine/googl
e', '/etc/google_appengine/google', '/etc/google_appengine/google']

Comment: I think this is because google is not a python file it is a directory.

Comment: I got the issue there is a python module inside my virtual environment which got installed while installing cloud storage. whenever i imported google this local module was imported, not the google appengine.